# Any way to use string (without escaping manually) that contains double quotes

Tags: c#

Let's say I want to assign a text (which contains many double quotes) into variable. However, the only way seems to manually escape:

```
string t = "Lorem \"Ipsum\" dummy......
//or//
string t = @"Lorem ""Ipsum"" dummy.....
```

Is there any way to avoid manual escaping, and instead use something universal (which I dont know in C#) keywoard/method to do that automatically? In PHP, it's untoldly simple, by just using single quote:

```
$t = 'Lorem "Ipsum" dummy .......
```

---

btw, please don't bomb me with critiques "Why do you need to use that" or etc. I need answer to the question what I ask.

Comment: If it's a lot of text, place it in a file and use it as an embedded resource. If you want something similar to using single quotes, you may use something like this: `string t = "Lorem 'Ipsum' dummy........".Replace("'", "\"");` _assuming you don't have single quotes in your string_.

Comment: Select the text in your IDE, use "find and replace" method to replace all occurences in a selection of `"` to `\"`. I think it would nbe the simpliest.

Comment: how would the PHP approach work with "...industry's standard..." in the sample?

Comment: Some other options listed here; though none any simpler than escaping with a slash: http://davidgiard.com/2018/11/02/EmbeddingQuotesWithinACString.aspx. Depending on your need one may be appropriate though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In C# syntax, the only way to define string literals is the use of the double quote " with optional modifiers @ and/or $ in front. The single quote is the [character literal delimiter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/), and cannot be used in the way PHP would allow - in any version, including the current 8.0.
Note that the PHP approach suffers from the need to escape ' as well, which is, especially in the English language, frequently used as the apostrophe.

To back that up, the EBNF of the string literal in current C# is still this:

```
regular_string_literal '"' { regular_string_literal_character } '"'
```

The only change in the compiler in version 8.0 was that now, the order of the prefix modifiers $ (interpolated) and @ (verbatim) can be either @$ or $@; it used to matter annoyingly in earlier versions.

Alternatives:

Save it to a file and use `File.ReadAllText` for the assignment, or embed it as a managed ressource, then the compiler will provide a variable in the namespace of your choice with the verbatim text as its runtime value.

Or use single quotes (or any other special character of your choice), and go

```
var t = @"Text with 'many quotes' inside".Replace("'", @"""");
```

where the `Replace` part could be modeled as an extension to the `String` class for brevity.

Comment: no, PHP wouldnt either suffer if text has `'` single quotes. you can put that in double quotes ----> `" abc'd eftgeg'zvbfsdfg"`.   If you emphasize on MIXED TEXT (which includes both single and doubles), then that's problem for any language. But this question is specifically for double quotes.

Comment: you have a mixed case in your sample text, that's why I addressed that.

Answer (score 5):

I know this answer may not be satisfying, but C# sytnax simply won't allow you to do such thing (at the time of writing this answer).

I think the best solution is to use resources. Adding/removing and using strings from resources is super easy:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myStringVariable = Strings.MyString;

        Console.WriteLine(myStringVariable);
    }
}
```

The `Strings` is the name of the resources file without the extension (`resx`):

[image]

`MyString` is the name of your string in the resources file:

[image]

I may be wrong, but I conjecture this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Not only it is "the best solution", is the way to go (IMHO). It simplifies edition, management, and can be used for localization easily in WF and WPF, and ASP.